# Android strange behavior with listview and custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have a problem with a list view and a custom cursor adapter and I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. Basically, in my activity I call initalize() that does a bunch of stuff to handle getting the proper data and initializing the listview. On first run of the activity you can see from the images that one of the items is missing from the list. If I go to another activity and go back to this activity the item that was missing shows up. I believe it has something to do with setContentView(R.layout.parent). If I move that to my initialize() then the item never shows up even when returning from another activity. So, for some reason, returning from another activity bypasses setContentView(R.layout.parent) and everything works fine. I know it's impossible for me to bypass setContentView(R.layout.parent) so I need to figure out what the problem is. Also, I did not include the layout because it is nothing more then two textviews.

Also, the images I have attached do not show that the missing item is the last one on the list.[image][image]

Custom Cursor Adapter:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;

public CustomCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, 
      Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 final View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

 return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    if (c.getColumnName(0).matches("section")){

        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("section");
        String section = c.getString(nameCol);

        TextView section_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        if ((section.length() > 0)) {

            section_text.setText(section);

        }   else {
         //so we don't have an empty spot
            section_text.setText("");
            section_text.setVisibility(2);
            section_text.setHeight(1);
        }

    } else if (c.getColumnName(0).matches("code")) {


        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("code");
        String mCode = c.getString(nameCol);
        TextView code_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        if (code_text != null) {
      int i = 167;
      byte[] data = {(byte) i};
      String strSymbol = EncodingUtils.getString(data, "windows-1252");

         mCode = strSymbol + " " + mCode;
            code_text.setText(mCode);
            code_text.setSingleLine();
        }

    }

    if (c.getColumnName(1).matches("title")){

        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("title");
        String mTitle = c.getString(nameCol);
        TextView title_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        if (title_text != null) {

            title_text.setText(mTitle);
        }

    } else if (c.getColumnName(1).matches("excerpt")) {


        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("excerpt");
        String mExcerpt = c.getString(nameCol);
        TextView excerpt_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        if (excerpt_text != null) {

            excerpt_text.setText(mExcerpt);
            excerpt_text.setSingleLine();

        }
    }
}
```

The Activity:

```
public class parent extends ListActivity {
private static String[] TITLE_FROM = {  SECTION, TITLE, _ID,  };
private static String[] CODE_FROM = { CODE, EXCERPT, _ID,  };
private static String ORDER_BY = _ID + " ASC";
private static int[] TO = { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, };



String breadcrumb = null;

private MyData data;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
CharSequence parent_id = "";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      


    data = new MyData(this);

    db = data.getReadableDatabase();

    setContentView(R.layout.parent);


    initialize();


}

public void initialize() {

 breadcrumb = null;
 Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
 TextView tvBreadCrumb;
 tvBreadCrumb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.breadcrumb); 

    if (bun == null) {
     //this is the first run 
     tvBreadCrumb.setText(null);
  tvBreadCrumb.setHeight(0);
        parent_id = "0";
        try {
         Cursor cursor = getData(parent_id);
         showSectionData(cursor);
        } finally {
         data.close();
        }
    } else {
     CharSequence state = bun.getString("state");
  breadcrumb = bun.getString("breadcrumb");
  tvBreadCrumb.setText(breadcrumb);

  CharSequence code = bun.getString("code");
        parent_id = code;

     if (state.equals("chapter")) {

            try {
             Cursor cursor = getData(parent_id);
             showSectionData(cursor);
            } finally {
             data.close();
            }

     } else if (state.equals("code")) {

            try {
             Cursor cursor = getCodeData(parent_id);
             showCodeData(cursor);
            } finally {
             data.close();
            }

     }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

 //initialize();
 super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {

 initialize();
 super.onResume();
}


private Cursor getData(CharSequence parent_id) {

 Cursor cTitles = db.query(TITLES_TABLE_NAME, TITLE_FROM, "parent_id = " + parent_id, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
 Cursor cCodes = db.query(CODES_TABLE_NAME, CODE_FROM, "parent_id = " + parent_id, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
 Cursor[] c = {cTitles, cCodes};
 Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(c);
 startManagingCursor(cursor);
 return cursor;
}

private Cursor getCodeData(CharSequence parent_id2) {
    Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
 CharSequence intent = bun.getString("intent");
 CharSequence searchtype = bun.getString("searchtype");
  //SQLiteDatabase db = data.getReadableDatabase();
 if (intent != null) {
  String sWhere = null; 
      if(searchtype.equals("code")) {
       sWhere = "code LIKE '%"+parent_id2+"%'";
      } else if(searchtype.equals("within")){
       sWhere = "definition LIKE '%"+parent_id2+"%'";
      }
      //This is a search request
  Cursor cursor = db.query(CODES_TABLE_NAME, CODE_FROM, sWhere, null, null, null, ORDER_BY); 
  startManagingCursor(cursor);
     return cursor;
 } else {
  Cursor cursor = db.query(CODES_TABLE_NAME, CODE_FROM, "parent_id = "+ parent_id2, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
  startManagingCursor(cursor);
     return cursor;
 }

}

private void showSectionData(Cursor cursor) {
 CustomCursorAdapter adapter= new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, TITLE_FROM, TO);
 setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private void showCodeData(Cursor cursor) {
 CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, CODE_FROM, TO);
 setListAdapter(adapter);
 Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
 CharSequence intent = bun.getString("intent");
 if (intent != null) {
  Cursor cursor1 = ((CursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).getCursor();
  startManagingCursor(cursor1);
  TextView tvBreadCrumb;
  tvBreadCrumb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.breadcrumb); 
  tvBreadCrumb.setText(cursor1.getCount() + " Records Found");
  //cursor1.close(); //mdl
 }
}
```

Comment: In the List view which you are using , how you are specifying the layout_height ? is it "wrap_content" ? If yes , try with some hard coded dimension like 240dp , check if that works fine, in main activity and coming back from another activity , Is it consistent !?

Comment: I tried your suggestion everything appears as it should. What exactly does this mean?

Comment: Everything works if I set a size on the TextView layout_height. This really does not solve my problem because I don't want the TextView to show if there is nothing to put in it.

Comment: I just noticed that the code I posed had an error in BindView on the Cursor Adapter It should have been              section_text.setText("");
             section_text.setVisibility(2);
             section_text.setHeight(1);

Comment: So yes, your suggestion fixed the problem, kinda. Now I have empty TextView at the top and I really wanted to avoid having a blank space if there's nothing to show.

Comment: ok , In one of the video lectures from Google IO 2010 about list view it was told that not to use wrap_content , because framework has to make some calculations(about child elements height ) and it has to draw the list view !! So I thought it might be the same issue , In that presentation it was suggested to use either hard coded dimension or fill_parent. Its general about listview .If you want to avoid showing textview if text is blank , why don't you set visibility of the textview as invisible or gone when there is nothing to display.

Comment: sat, if you notice in my code example I am using setvisibility(view.GONE) and that is hiding more then it should. I really think something is wrong with my code. If I leave this activity and return to it PART 5 shows up ---- until I scroll to the top and then back to the bottom (that's where PART 5 is).

Comment: sat, I tired your suggestion with fill_parent and it did not fix my problem. Behavior is the same. I do appreciate the comment though and thanks for the info on Goole IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem and as I suspected it was a problem with my code. Setting the TextView's visibility to view.GONE or view.INVISIBLE works great. The problem was that I never made it visible again. I never called view.VISIBLE and that caused a whole bunch of problems.

```
 if (c.getColumnName(0).matches("section")){

    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("section");
    String section = c.getString(nameCol);

    TextView section_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    if ((section.length() > 0)) {

        section_text.setText(section);
        // I forgot this!!!!!
        section_text.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

    }   else {
     //so we don't have an empty spot
        section_text.setVisibility(view.GONE);

    }

}
```